# How to install dell command and configure tool on dell inspiron 5520 running ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I am trying to install dell command and configure on my dell inspiron 5520 runing ubuntu 20.04 os. I am following [this instruction](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000178000/dell-command-configure).

When I execute

```
sudo dpkg -i srvadmin-hapi_9.5.0_amd64.deb
```

I get following error:

```
(Reading database ... 654921 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack srvadmin-hapi_9.5.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking srvadmin-hapi (9.5.0) over (9.5.0) ...
Setting up srvadmin-hapi (9.5.0) ...
Job for instsvcdrv.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status instsvcdrv.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
dpkg: error processing package srvadmin-hapi (--install):
 installed srvadmin-hapi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 srvadmin-hapi
```

I executed

```
systemctl status instsvcdrv.service
```

Output:

```
instsvcdrv.service - Systems Management Device Drivers
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/instsvcdrv.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-24 13:23:14 IST; 3min 14s ago
    Process: 762908 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/instsvcdrv-helper start (code=exited, status=155)
    
Aug 24 13:23:14 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting Systems Management Device Drivers...
Aug 24 13:23:14 xxxx systemd[1]: instsvcdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=155/n/a
Aug 24 13:23:14 xxxx systemd[1]: instsvcdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 13:23:14 xxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Systems Management Device Drivers.
```

I executed

```
journalctl -xe
```

Output:

```
-- Subject: A start job for unit openvpn@server.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit openvpn@server.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2641966.
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Options error: --ca fails with 'ca.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Options error: --cert fails with 'server.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: WARNING: cannot stat file 'server.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Options error: --key fails with 'server.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: WARNING: cannot stat file 'ta.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Options error: --tls-auth fails with 'ta.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx ovpn-server[764772]: Use --help for more information.
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit openvpn@server.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit openvpn@server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 13:31:48 xxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit openvpn@server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit openvpn@server.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2641966 and the job result is failed.
```

BIOS Information

```
Vendor: Dell Inc.
Version: A11
Release Date: 10/03/2012
Address: 0xE0000
Runtime Size: 128 kB
ROM Size: 4608 kB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    PNP is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    EDD is supported
    Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
    Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
    5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
    8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
    Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Printer services are supported (int 17h)
    CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    Smart battery is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Function key-initiated network boot is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
    UEFI is supported
Firmware Revision: 1.1
```

System Information

```
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Inspiron 5520
Version: A11
Serial Number: XXXXXXX
UUID: X-X-X-X-X
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: xxx123x#ABA
Family: 103C_5335KV
```

How do I resolve these issues and install the tool successfully?

Comment: This question got answered here https://askubuntu.com/q/1363450/795530